# Private constructor and final instance variables

Tags: java, final, private-constructor

If you create a class with uninitialized `final` variables and a `private` default constructor, the compiler screams at you that you have uninitialized `final` variables.  That's all well and dandy, except that the constructor is now just unreachable code.  So is this just oversight from the Java creators or is there a logical, behind the scenes reason for this?  Or is my assumption that the constructor is unreachable code wrong?

Comment: Private constructors accessible inside that class and expectation from class that has a private constructor is to have a static method that returns instance of itself

Comment: @ConvertToInt32, oh, I didn't even think of code calling the constructor from inside the class.  I mainly only use private constructors when I want to ensure they're not used to instantiate an object

Comment: Take a look at singleton pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the 'screaming' would occur regardless of the constructor access level (private/public/protected/package)... these issues are handled separately.

On the one level, the compiler makes sure that IF constructor is (somehow, miraculously) invoked than all final variables are initialized.

Then on a different level we worry about constructor reachability. Which is a bit more complex because obviously you could later add factory methods, and furthermore you could reach it with ugly reflection code using "setAccessible(true)"